# OpenGL matrices - cannot figure correct ones

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, projection, render-to-texture

**Edit:** Summarizing what I want to do, more concise:

Render a texture of size `wi,hi` to an output texture `wo,ho`, so that the aspect ratio of input texture is maintained, and it fits inside the output texture, eventually with black borders if aspect ratio is different. For this I want to use a perspective projection, as I may rotate or apply other transforms to the input texture.

Then I want this output texture to be displayed on screen, with size `ws, hs`, where `hs` may be larger than `ws`. Again, maintaining aspect ratio and fitting with black borders. Here an orthogonal projection should be enough, as only rendering to screen is required, no further processing.

I want to do it without hacks, in order to make my life easier in case I want later to rotate, scale the original texture. I can figure by trial and error how to modify the parameters to get what I want now, but would rather use each matrix in the way it is intended.

Comment: Possible to post some images of what you are getting?

Comment: My 2cents; it is very uncommon to scale objects in a non uniform way to adapt to the target texture/display ratio, the usual way to deal with ratio is to only play with the frustumM's left/right/bottom/up parameters (actually most 3d games will use perspectiveM instead, which needs only one parameter to handle the ratio: aspect)

Comment: @VB_overflow: Agreed. I read some literature about these matrices, but cannot figure how to apply it to this specific situation (so that I use the matrices according to their roles).

Comment: I have trouble to understand the question after the edit. The usual process is like this: you render something (a 3d model, a sprite ...) into a texture `Ti` of size `wi,hi`, now you want to render `Ti` into another texture `To` (or the screen) of dimension `wo, ho`, preserving aspect and centering; for that you need to render a _quad_ mapped with `Ti` inside `To`, using a classic 2D orthographic matrix. The problem is then to find the position `x, y`and the size `w, h`of the quad. Is it what you want to do ?

Comment: @VB_overflow: The steps are shifted in your description. In my question I consider first texture (an image) as i (input), the rendered texture as output (o) and the screen size ws, hs. Don't think of it in terms of games but rather general processing. Fit by scaling a rectangle with original dimensions wi, hi inside a rectangle wo, ho. Then fit wo, ho, again by scaling without modifying aspect ratio, inside rectangle ws, hs. I want to do this with OpenGL matrices. I actually have a solution, but since I already offered a bounty, I'll let it open, and maybe improve my solution.